# How can I setup selenium grid for Parallel execution without using TestNG.xml file.?

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, testng, selenium-grid

I am trying to see if we can execute our testcases on selenium Grid in Parallel mode without using TestNg.xml file.
I know we can setup parameters in TestNg.xml file and set it to run in parallel, and use those parameter to initialize the driver to run the suite on parallel mode on grid. But is there any way I can do it without using TestNg.xml file?

Can I use Threads or Runnable interface?

Please suggest if it is possible and if that method is recommended.

Comment: Are you using cucumber ?

Comment: No, I am using testNg and Selenium. But I would like to see how parallel execution is achievable on grid without using TestNG.xml file. I am trying to find the Best and Optimal way to achieve parallel execution on grid. If using TestNg.xml is only the best way, then TestNG.xml it is.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can **use**
**Threads or Runnable interface** but if we are initializing thread, we need to **be careful** on running our code on different machines and different environments.

like

IN case of **2 core** machine, it is capable of running **upto 4 threads**, if you exceeded, you might end up **out of memory exception**.

same way

IN case of **8 core** machine, it is capable of running **upto 16 threads**, if you are running only **4** threads, it is **not efficient**.

That is where **TestNG** is helpful, because TestNG is internally calculating cores and threads of the machine, do the thread allocation. i suggest to use xml file configuration. **please do not use Runnable interface**